# How to get such kind of dialog?

Tags: android, material-design, android-alertdialog, dialogfragment

[image: this is fab button]

[image: this kind of pop up should appear on clicking fab button]

I want to have kind of pop shown in the given images. What should use ? Pop window, dialog or alert dialog. i have tried all of these, but not able to match the exact UI.

Comment: its a **[PopupMenu](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html)**

Comment: Use `popup menu/dialog` for show dialog like you want.

Comment: "i have tried all of these, but not able to match the exact UI." Show what you have tried and what the result is, then you can get help on what to update / fix.

Comment: Use pop up menu more [Link](http://tutlane.com/tutorial/android/android-popup-menu-with-examples)

Comment: You could also use Material Dialogs library its much easier and faster to implement.
https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use [Popup menu](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html) for this purpose.**

[image]

Add this code in your activity.java :

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(HomeActivity.this, fab);
                popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home, popup.getMenu());
                popup.setGravity(Gravity.END);

                popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.action_settings:
                                // your action
                            default:
                                return true;
                        }
                    }
                });

                popup.show();
            }
        });
```

In `style.xml`

```
  <style name="MyPopupMenu" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow">
    <item name="fontPath">Muli_Regular.ttf</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownHorizontalOffset">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset">57dp</item>
</style>
```

use this **style** in activity theme as :

```
<item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/MyPopupMenu</item>
```

Comment: you can change this margins in style accordingly your requirement.