# Spinner not showing onclick of menu item in toolbar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I want to show Dialog spinner onclick of my menu item..below is my code

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.months, menu);
        MenuItem monthChooser = menu.findItem(R.id.monthChooser);
        monthChooser.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                Spinner monthsList = new Spinner(Attandance_Chart.this,Spinner.MODE_DIALOG);
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                list.add("January");
                list.add("February");
                list.add("March");
                list.add("April");
                list.add("May");
                list.add("June");
                list.add("July");
                list.add("August");
                list.add("September");
                list.add("October");
                list.add("November");
                list.add("December");
                Toast.makeText(Attandance_Chart.this, "click aayichi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Attandance_Chart.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
                monthsList.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
               // layout.addView(monthsList);
                return true;
            }
        });

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

**When i click menu item, toast is getting printed..but spinner is not showing..Thanks in advance!!!.**

Below is i add images:

[image]

Comment: you need to insert the spinner in some layout for it to be visible. you can create a Dialog popup and add spinner to it. Then on click on the button you can just open the dialog popup

Comment: But i need it on click of menu item & need to create it pragmatically

Comment: Create one custom layout. create one custom dialog for that and dialog.show on menu item click.

Comment: you ned to add it to some layout which is visible in that page

Comment: try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48048033/8089770

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you used below code...

```
     monthsList.performClick()
```